# Cast object to class that implements it

Tags: c#, class, casting

System class

```
public class View
{
    //5 different constructors

    public virtual bool OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
    {
        //Can't see inside
    }
}
```

---

I need to override this `OnTouchEvent`, so I tried like this:

```
public class MyClass : SystemClass
{
    public override View GetCellCore(/*params*/)
    {
        View v = base.GetCellCore(/*params*/);
        MyView mv = (MyView)mv;
        return mv;
    }

    private class MyView : View
    {
        //Implementation of the 5 different constructors

        public override bool OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
        {
            //Do something
            return base.OnTouchEvent(e);
        }
    }
}
```

I need this `OnTouchEvent` to be overridden so I can get the touch info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're trying to do can't work for the same reason why this can't work:

```
object obj = new object();
Dog dog = (Dog)object;
```

`Dog` inherits from `object` just as it inherits from `Animal` (because everything inherits from `object`.) But you can probably see why it wouldn't make sense to be able to do this. Just as an example:

```
Animal cat = new Cat();
Dog dog = (Dog)cat;

object date = DateTime.Now;
Dog dog = (Dog)date;
```

If objects could be cast this way then literally anything could be cast as anything else, and types would have no meaning.

Another way of looking at it is that an object only has one type. If you create an instance of `Dog`, the type of that object is `Dog`. It will never be anything else, ever. It can be cast as one of its base types or cast as an interface that it implements, but that doesn't change its type.

To illustrate:

```
Dog dog = new Dog(); // It's a Dog
Animal animal = (Animal)dog; // It's cast as an Animal, but it's still a Dog.
object obj = (object)animal; // It's cast as an object, but it's still a Dog.
```

Perhaps that helps to demonstrate that casting cannot and does not change the type of an object. So the only way you can cast an `Animal` as a `Dog` is if the `Animal` is *already* a `Dog`.

Like this:

```
var poodle = new Poodle(); // inherits from Dog
var animal = (Animal)poodle;
var dog = (Dog)animal;
```

This won't throw an exception because the poodle is an `Animal` and a `Dog.` If this clears up any confusion, after these three lines of code execute, there's still only one object. We're not creating new objects, just new variables that refer to the same object.

Comment: very well explained

Answer (score 0):

A Dog is an Animal (inheritance)
An Animal is not always a Dog (it's why it doesn't run in your example) but could be (it's why it compiles).

Answer (score 0):

I think about as close as you are going to get is an Animal constructor on Dog.  But it still does not make much sense.

```
public class Dog : Animal 
{
    public void Woof()
    { }
    public int DogTag { get; set; }  //you would have to make this up
    public Dog()
    { }
    public Dog (Animal animal) 
    {
        //now the dog is nothing more than an animal
    }
}

Dog dog = new Dog(animal);
```

Comment: However you have a probem if the provided `Animal` is a `Cat`.

Comment: @HimBromBeere No you don't.  The Dog is still nothing more than an Animal.

Answer (score -4):

> The Animal is a system class, the object is created internally

This is not possible because there is no gurantee at all that your system class is indeed one of your custom classes. However you could implement custom conversion logic if you cannot influence the system class.

```
public sealed class SystemClass
{
}

public class CustomClass
{
    private SystemClass _systemClass;

    public CustomClass(SystemClass systemClass)
    {
        _systemClass = systemClass;
    }

    public static explicit operator CustomClass(SystemClass systemClass)
    {
        return new CustomClass(systemClass);
    }

    public static implicit operator SystemClass(CustomClass customClass)
    {
        return customClass._systemClass;
    }
}
```

So that you can add addional functionality while preserving compatibility with your underlying infrastructure.

```
var system = new SystemClass();
var custom = (CustomClass)system;
```

Comment: Havig an explicit cast is a really *bad* idea, as not every `Animal` *can* be converted to `Dog`.

Comment: I would really not recommend doing this. First it requires that you "make up" some of the properties of `Dog` just to create a new one.

Comment: This wouldn't compile anyway, as conversion operators can't convert to/from derived classes (error CS0554).